# Restore database as

Tags: sql-server

when doing the database restore in the "options" pane, there is a section name "Restore the database as:". What does this actually say?

thanks

Comment: I've voted to close as "belongs on serverfault.com" as this is a question that's technically about sql server administration, rather than programming.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the section called "Restore the database files as"? Just press F1 and Books Online will open at the correct page with the explanation.